# How to protect against clickjacking && slow post on a site running through Cloudfront, EC2 and a static site on S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cloudfront, clickjacking

I am hosting a static react site on S3 and running my server on an EC2 instance. My production version is running through Cloudfront to attach the HTTPS certficates.

After a third party ran a test to search for security flaws, click jacking, X-Frame-Options aren't set and a slow post vulnerability are the only issues that remain.

I am hoping that the below code in my Node/express server should solve both the X-Frame-Options issue as well as the click jacking but am unsure since I believe (but very uncertain) that these solutions may need to be accomplished within Cloudfront/AWS.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
  next();
});
```

I also understand that one of the ways to protect against slow post attacks to set a timeout to endpoints (which defaults to 2 minutes). I was wondering what a recommended timeout should be (40mb limit on uploaded files should be kept in mind and users could have a variety of internet connectivity but all in a first world country) and where within a server to implement this?

Thanks in advances for any solutions/clarification.

Comment: did you manage to protect against clickjacking? I have a very similar setup and am also finding a solution to protect against clickjacking.

Comment: was never able to confirm if the above worked, I no longer have access to that repo so cannot confirm anymore unfortunately